# nodejs : TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, typeerror

I have written below code to read a xml and return a hashmap:

```
this.xmlObjectRepositoryLoader = function (xmlPath, callback){
        var map = {}
        var innerMap = {};
        var el;
        fs.readFile(xmlPath, "utf-8",function(err, data) {
            if(err){
                console.log('File not found!!')
            }
            else{
                console.log(data)
                var doc = domparser.parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
                var els = doc.getElementsByTagName("Child");
                for(var i =0 ; i< els .length;i++){
                    var e = elements[i];
                    eName = e.getAttribute("a");
                    var params = elm.getElementsByTagName("abc");
                    innerMap = {};
                    for(var j =0 ; j< params.length;j++){
                        var param = params[j];
                        var b = param.getAttribute("b");
                        var c= param.getAttribute("c");
                        innerMap[b] = c;
                    }
                    map[el] = innerMap;
                    innerMap={};
                };
            }
            console.log(map);
            return callback(map);
        });        
    };
```

And I am calling `xmlObjectRepositoryLoader` from below method but it returns error as `TypeError: callback is not a function`:

```
this.objectLoader = function(filePath){
        if (filePath.includes(".xml")) {
            console.log(this.xmlObjectRepositoryLoader(filePath));
    }
```

Can you please let me know where I am wrong and how can I resolve this

Comment: Hope before downvoting, people should have given reason also. Anyways Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to call `callback`, here:

```
return callback(map);
```

However, you're not passing a callback to `xmlObjectRepositoryLoader`:

```
console.log(this.xmlObjectRepositoryLoader(filePath));
```

Do this instead:

```
this.xmlObjectRepositoryLoader(filePath, function(map){ 
    console.log(map)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I dont have the reputation to comment. I am putting in this in answer. Sorry for that. U missed the parameter in the code below

```
this.objectLoader = function(filePath){
        if (filePath.includes(".xml")) {
            console.log(this.xmlObjectRepositoryLoader(filePath));
    }
```

> this.xmlObjectRepositoryLoader(filePath)

in the above line.

And u can include a validation in the function **xmlObjectRepositoryLoader** to check whether callback is a function or not and then call it to avoid the error thrown (if its not a mandatory parameter).